# PopOverController not working properly in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, ios5, user-interface, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

i have a problem with my story board splitview application. I have this popover controller but when i press the bar button item instead of popping on top of the screen it gets pushed from the side. Any thoughts?

```
    - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{    
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.popoverController =nil;
    // self.masterPopoverController = ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just give a try with this :

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)popoverController {
barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
NSMutableArray *items = [[_toolbar items] mutableCopy];
[items insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
[_toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
self.popover = popoverController;
```

}

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {    
NSMutableArray *items = [[_toolbar items] mutableCopy];
[items removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[_toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
self.popover = nil;
```

}

Comment: that didn't work =[, i added a toolbar and then the button showed up but when pressed it did nothing

Comment: Have you set the connection of button to the method?

Comment: i don't know if it is a iOS sim thing but when i use iOS 5.0 it works fine and looks fine but when i use 5.1 the arrow is gone